# Declaring Types in Groovy

Tags: groovy, types

When you don't declare a type for a variable in groovy, it is my understanding that the java virtual machine has to use reflection in order to figure out what type the object is before executing any methods and has the potential of throwing a runtime error.

If that is correct, what about when you declare the type? Does the java virtual machine still end up using reflection because the original code was in groovy? Or is my understanding of this whole matter incorrect in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't appear as though type declarations have any specific influence on how Groovy invokes the method. Essentially, as noted [on the Groovy wiki](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Method+Invokation), instead of simply invoking the method, Groovy will call `invokeMethod()` on the object's metaclass, which either delegates to a method defined in the metaclass or performs a reflective lookup of the method.

It's worth noting that the metaclass makes use of a [MetaMethod](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/MetaMethod.html), which, in the worst case, uses a cached reflection lookup, i.e., it only needs to make a single reflective lookup.

**Edit**

Some of this overhead may be avoidable by using [groovypp](http://code.google.com/p/groovypptest/), which adds static typing capabilities to Groovy code.

Comment: Groovypp looks very interesting. Thanks for that one!

Answer (score 24):

The best way to investigate this kind of problem is to look at the generated byte-code yourself.  If you create two sample classes:

WithType.groovy:

```
class WithType {
    String name

    String returnName() { getName() }
}
```

WithoutType.groovy:

```
class WithoutType {
    def name

    def returnName() { getName() }
}
```

Compile them with `groovyc`:

```
% groovyc WithType.groovy
% groovyc WithoutType.groovy
```

And then use `javap` to spit out the human readable bytecode:

```
% javap -c WithType > WithType.txt
% javap -c WithoutType > WithoutType.txt
```

You can then diff the 2 files and look for the `returnName()` method to see how they're handled differently in how they call the generated `getName()` method for the name field.  If you find the `returnName()` method, you'll see that the WithType version looks like this:

```
public java.lang.String returnName();
  Code:
   0:   invokestatic    #24; //Method $getCallSiteArray:()[Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;
   3:   astore_1
   4:   aload_1
   5:   ldc #47; //int 0
   7:   aaload
   8:   aload_0
   9:   invokeinterface #53,  2; //InterfaceMethod org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite.callCurrent:(Lgroovy/lang/GroovyObject;)Ljava/lang/Object;
   14:  invokestatic    #56; //Method $get$$class$java$lang$String:()Ljava/lang/Class;
   17:  invokestatic    #38; //Method org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
   20:  checkcast   #58; //class java/lang/String
   23:  areturn
   24:  nop
```

and the untyped one looks like this:

```
public java.lang.Object returnName();
  Code:
   0:   invokestatic    #24; //Method $getCallSiteArray:()[Lorg/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite;
   3:   astore_1
   4:   aload_1
   5:   ldc #47; //int 0
   7:   aaload
   8:   aload_0
   9:   invokeinterface #53,  2; //InterfaceMethod org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite.callCurrent:(Lgroovy/lang/GroovyObject;)Ljava/lang/Object;
   14:  areturn
   15:  nop
```

The untyped one has fewer instructions because it doesn't need to do any type checking or String conversion on what it's returning.  The actual method call to `getName()` is the same in both the typed and untyped versions:

```
   9:   invokeinterface #53,  2; //InterfaceMethod org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite.callCurrent:(Lgroovy/lang/GroovyObject;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

You can see that it's calling an interface method on the groovy CallSite method and passing in a GroovyObject.  [CallSite](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSite.html) is an interface that's implemented by a bunch of the groovy metaObject code.  So this is the call to the groovy MOP that dynamically invokes the `getName()` method.

(this is all with groovy 1.7.5)

Comment: You'll have to forgive me because my knowledge of the JVM is pretty thin.  Is every instruction taking the same amount of time to execute?  Or is it possible that the 4 methods in "without type" are going faster than the single method in "with type"?

Comment: There are 3 more methods "with type" than "without type".  "With type" adds 3 instructions that don't appear in the untyped one (invokestatic #56 (get string class), invokestatic #38 (cast to string), and checkcast #58 (check the cast is OK)).  So it's a pure superset of the instructions and the instructions are simple checks of the cast to the string so would not be faster.  Note that this bytecode was generated with groovy 1.7.5 and it'd be worth checking what recent versions of groovy generate.

Comment: So, again, and this is probably me not understanding the JVM very well...  Do all instructions take the same amount of time?

Comment: No, instructions can take a variable number of clock cycles to execute and really depend on how the JVM optimizes them and turns them into actual instruction code (and how hot the JVM is, etc).  All I'm saying above is that typing adds additional checks but doesn't take anything away.  Unless you're in a really tight loop that is being executed a LOT, I'm betting you'd never see a perf difference with the cast, that's been optimized a lot and might even be optimized out by the JIT at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

It still makes heavy use of reflection.
One of the things you must have in mind, is that the methods calls are resolved at runtime.
Easiest way to see it

```
Integer.metaClass.xxx << {println "hi"}
Integer ten = 10
ten.xxx()
```

This compiles, even though a normal Integer 100 would not have method xxx.
The first line adds the method to the class, but the compiler would not know this at compile time (the method is added at runtime).
It does not matter that the type is known, groovy still uses reflection to perform the calls.
Another example.

```
def (Number i, Number l) = [100, 100L]
print i
print l
def print(Number n)  {println "Number $n"}
def print(Integer n) {println "Integer $n"}
```

In java, it would print Number 100 twice, as the method is statically selected.
Groovy doesn't care and just selects the method based on the class of the arguments at runtime.

Comment: tim_yates comment on Anto's answer also shows that it's possible for the metaclass to override default properties, which means that even if you invoke, e.g. `equals()`, `hashCode()` or `toString()`, Groovy still needs to make a metaclass lookup. Especially since Groovy allows per-instance metaclass changes, e.g., `Integer ten = 10; ten.metaClass.toString = { println "I'm the number $delegate!" }; ten.toString()` prints "I'm the number 10!"

Comment: Wow! thanks +1 for good explanation :) and thanks for clearing my doubt too :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some charts to answer your question from the creators of groovy++ on:

https://code.google.com/p/groovypptest/wiki/Performance

They are showing Groovy is slow (depending on the algorithm between 10 and 100 times slower). This is not only caused by dynamic typing, excessive use of reflection and dynamically invoked methods. It handles object arrays as lists. So it works completely around the native array handling of java. Which makes it also slower than Java. And not even groovy++ (the easiest way to optimize groovy programs) does address this fact.

But no matter how slow groovy code runs, I really like the abilities of the language and the fact that you can replace tons of jave lines with a few lines in groovy. Each language has its purpose. Java is good for flexibility and scalability, ruby is for fast prototyping (not so much for scaling) and Groovy is a very good solution to write fast prototypes with all the functionality of java that are almost as scalable as java code (also you can replace the slow running groovy code step by step with java or g++, as you need it).

Answer (score -3):

Hi it was a nice question but don't know whether that the JVM uses reflection to found these types. 
The thing you have to be through when you code groovy is that both Java and Groovy have differs only in the **source code**. When they have been run they have been bound to java object model. Regardless of whether you write Groovy classes or scripts, they run as Java classes inside the JVM. So regardless what you do, all these are converted to Java and run in JVM :)

Although the Java runtime understands compiled Groovy classes without any
problem, it doesn’t understand .groovy source files. More work has to happen
behind the scenes if you want to load .groovy files dynamically at runtime.
Make sure that Groovy syntax is **line-oriented**, but the **execution** is not. That is Groovy coed is not processed **Line By Line**(shocked!,ya have to, some trick is going on) Instead Groovy is fully parsed, and a class is been generated. This **generated class** act as a bridge between Java And Groovy.Groovy classes are generated such that their format is identical to Java bytecode. So as i mentioned before, since Groovy produce the same bytecode, and it runs in Jvm, the class loader can handle and this bytecode. If it sounds harsh, don't worry, all the things are done by **Groovy** by it, for us.

I recommend you to read **Groovy in action** book. Click [here](http://tinyurl.com/GroovyInAction)

Comment: Whilst it is true that Groovy is compiled to bytecode, I believe Groovy will still do some lookups as it will have to check the `metaClass` for any methods declared (or overridden) there

Comment: This isn't quite the information I was looking for. I am not interested in loading groovy dynamically at run time, rather I am interested in the performance and runtime characteristics of the compiled groovy code.

Comment: As for the comment from tim_yates -- do you know if the `metaClass` still has to be checked for types that are explicitly declared?

Comment: @KPthunder `Double.metaClass.toString = { "Double! $delegate" } ; Double d = 2.0 ; println( d.toString() )` prints out `Double! 2.0`