# Is there any difference between declaring a variable with 'def' and declaring it with a known type?

Tags: variables, groovy, function

Assuming I have a defined class

```
class MyClass {
}
```

Is there a hit in performance in runtime in doing `def c = new MyClass()` instead of `MyClass c = new MyClass()`? Or is it exactly the same?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338381/declaring-types-in-groovy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`def` is a replacement for a type name. In variable definitions it is used to indicate that you don't care about the type.

If you don't declare the type of variable, Groovy under the covers will be declared as type `Object`. You can think of `def` as an alias of `Object`.

In your example:

```
def c = new MyClass()
// transform to:
java.lang.Object c = new MyClass()
```

---

```
MyClass c = new MyClass()
// transform to:
MyClass c = new MyClass()
```