# What are the implications of using types for grails services?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I find myself avoiding the def keyword when programming in groovy because I like the unambiguity of using types. I'm wondering what are the implications of using types versus using def for injecting services? I guess it has a potential impact on testability with mock injection. Anything else?

I see both methods mentioned in [the documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/services.html).

What do people consider best practice now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be an issue with reloading of services injected into other services, when declared with explicit type (for pre-2.0 grails). I don't see anything current in grails jira about this, so this may have been fixed in more recent versions.

Comment: This does appear to still be an issue actually. I'm using grails 2.1 and I noticed that it was better at reloading spring injected services when they were def'd from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

`def` is a replacement for a type name. In variable definitions it is used to indicate that you don't care about the type. [Is there any difference between declaring a variable with 'def' and declaring it with a known type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8671695/462015)

```
def num = 1
Integer number = 2

assert num.class == Integer
assert number.class == Integer
```

I prefer use `def` for dependency injection and I think is the most common in Grails.