# Division returns unexpected 0 if result is declared as double

Tags: groovy, types

From the following code

```
x = 2 / 5
double y = 2 / 5
double z = 2.0 / 5
println(String.format("%f %f %f", x, y, z))
```

we get the output

```
0.4 0.0 0.4
```

Why is the value of `y` 0.0?  What is the reason for this unintuitive behaviour?

Comment: Is it perhaps because `2 / 5` is an integer division, returning 0, which is then cast to a double?  But then, why is `x` not 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because dividing two integers (2 and 5) gives that result 0, which is then converted to double.

Comment: But then, why is `x` 0.4?

Comment: In this SO question they mention that if you don't declare 
 a type it will use reflection to figure out the type, so it could be this, the reflection got the type for the division as double and probably it first evaluated the expression as such then assigned the value. In the second case it was already declared as double and it did not need to run reflection on it, it made the division as two integers.
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338381/declaring-types-in-groovy